# How to test the child component render text after the button on the parent component click with react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-testing-library

I have a parent component `App` and it has a button. When click button, it will call `axios` to get the posts and then render the posts items. `App` has a child component `Post` and `Post` has a child component `ListItem`. On my App test file, I have tested the axios can load correct after click button. However, I cannot test the rendered content. It cannot find the `data-testid`: `Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="test-axios-content"]`.

I use `react testing library`.

Here is my test file:

```
import React from "react"
import App from "../../App"
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor, act } from "../utils/test-utils"
import axios from "axios"

jest.mock("axios", () => {
    return {
        get: jest.fn()
    }
})

describe("App test", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks()
    })
    it("should load and display the data", async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)

        axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
            data: { title: "hello there", body: "abc" }
        })
        await act(async () => {
            fireEvent.click(getByTestId("test-axios-button"))
            expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
            const testingData = await waitFor(() => getByTestId("test-axios-content"))
            expect(testingData).toHaveTextContent("hello there")
        })
    })
})
```

The first axios calltime is correct but my testing cannot find the testId `test-axios-content`. I put it on my child component on the App.js.

App.js

```
...
function App() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
    const handleClick= async () => {
        const postsResult = await getPosts()
        setPosts(postsResult.data)
    }
    return (
        <div className="App" data-test="appComponent">
            <button data-testid="test-axios-button" onClick={handleClick}>
                get post from axios
            </button>
            <section>
                <div>Load Posts:</div>
                <Post posts={posts} data-testid="test-axios-content" />
            </section>
        </div>
}
...
```

api getPosts:

```
import axios from "axios"
export const getPosts = async () => await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10")
```

Post:

```
import ListItem from "../listItem"

const Post= (props) => {
    const posts = props.posts
    return (
        <>
            {posts.length > 0 && (
                <div>
                    {posts.map((post, index) => {
                        const { title, body } = post
                        return <ListItem key={title} title={title} desc={body} />
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    )
}

export default Post
```

ListItem:

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
    const { title, desc } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 data-test="title" data-testid="title">
                {title}
            </h2>
            <div data-test="desc" data-testid="desc">
                {desc}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListItem
```

Comment: Just a comment about the approach to unit testing... you've 3 components and you are testing a descendent component from the top component... this more more an integration test than it is a unit test. Perhaps start with a unit test on `ListItem` that it renders the passed `desc` and `title` props, then a unit test for `Post` where `ListItem` is mocked, etc... Your unit tests really shouldn't be touching more than one unit of code at a time. When you get to unit testing `App` then you know all the code under it has already been tested.

Comment: Yes, I have done the unit test for the children component.

Answer (score 1):

The first wrong part is that `posts` is one array, but on the `axios mock`, it's one object: `{ title: "hello there", body: "abc" }`. The correct format is : `[{ title: "hello there", body: "abc" }]`

So, on the `axios mock` part of testing, the correct code is:

```
axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
    data: [{ title: "hello there", body: "abc" }]
})
```

The second wrong part is rather than using `await act`, it should use trigger click first and then use `await waitFor` with a callback:

```
fireEvent.click(getByTestId("test-axios-button"))
await waitFor(() => {
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    const renderData = screen.getByText("hello there")
    expect(renderData).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

This is the final:

```
it("should load and display the data", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)

    axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
        data: [{ title: "hello there", body: "abc" }]
    })
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId("test-axios-button"))
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        const testingData = await waitFor(() => getByTestId("test-axios-content"))
        expect(testingData).toHaveTextContent("hello there")
    })
})
```